# Prevent default of scrolling to top on click

Tags: jquery

Test site:

https://josh-unger-4lts.squarespace.com/

I would like to prevent the document from scrolling to the top when the 3 line burger menu at the top of site is clicked.  This shows up shortly after scrolling down page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).find(".Mobile-bar-menu").on("click", function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: You are mixing JS and jQuery, which is confusing, and `getElementById` only takes `Id`'s, so delete the `.`

Comment: 1.`document.getElementById` takes `id` value only , not `.` or `#`.

2.Why mixing javascript/jQuery syntax's? Use either one purely.

Do like below:-

    `<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).find(".Mobile-bar-menu").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // or try event.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
    </script>`

Comment: @FlipFloop my code is updated to recent suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This code chunk I suggest was tested directly in the console of your live site.
It works.

```
// Global variable to remind the scrolled position on hamburger click
var pos=0;
$(document).find(".Mobile-bar-menu").on("click", function(event){
  pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(pos);
});

// On menu close, restore the scrolled position after the animation has finished.
$(".Mobile-overlay-close").click(function(){
    $(".Mobile.loaded").removeClass("expand");
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.scrollTo(0,pos);
    },400);
});
```

Now You should look to place this code parts at the right places...

Comment: This works perfectly to restore the scroll position.  However, the desired effect would be for it not to ever go to the top.

Comment: Find what makes it go to the top then. It doesn't look to be in the main page markup. It certainly is in a plugin script which creates that menu overlay.